# Migration From Quarkus 1.3.2.FInal to 1.4.2.Final affected Vault Access

Tags: quarkus

In my old setup for Quarkus 1.3.2.Final

I have this in my property file

```
quarkus.vault.url=${vault_path}
quarkus.vault.tls.use-kubernetes-ca-cert=true
quarkus.vault.authentication.kubernetes.role=${someVaultRole}
quarkus.vault.tls.ca-cert=${someTlsCertLocation}
quarkus.vault.kv-secret-engine-mount-path=${someSecretEngingPath}
```

when i tried to access the secrets using VaultKVSecretEngine.readSecret(path), it gives me the secrets for that path

But when I try to migrate to Quarkus 1.4.2.Final, I got this error

`"io.quarkus.vault.runtime.client.VaultClientException code=403 body={\"errors\":[\"1 error occurred:\\n\\t* permission denied\\n\\n\"]}\`

when i tried to call VaultKVSecretEngine.readSecret(path) with my old setup.

Question is, what are the configs in my application.properties that i missed for quarkus 1.4.2.final vault access?

Answer (score 0):

since by default, quarkus 1.4.2.Final uses kv-secret-engine-version 2, it is needed to specify the kv-secret-engine-version to version 1 when migrating from quarkus 1.3.2.Final to 1.4.2.Final since 1.3.2.Final uses kv-secret-engine-version 1